# How to pass a closure to send in Ruby as an argument

Tags: ruby, closures, send

I use `send` like this:

```
[:last, :first].map { |sym| [0,1,2].send(sym) }
#=> [2, 0]
```

I am trying to pass to `send` a symbol of index and rindex, and a closure for their execution:

```
[:rindex, :index].map { |sym| [0,1,2].send(sym, { |x| x %2 == 0  }) }
```

I get an error message:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '}'
...p { |sym| [0,1,2].send(sym, { |x| x %2 == 0  }) }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, Ruby has pretty expressive `Integer#even?` method, which you can pass with an ampersand: `[:rindex, :index ].map { |sym| [0,1,2].send(sym, &:even?) }`

Comment: @Ilya edited my answer 8 seconds before you posted this comment :D

Comment: @Andrey, you deleted your answer, then undeleted and so on. Maybe you'll delete it again, who knows.

Comment: no one knows what it's like to be the bad man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

In Ruby, blocks are being passed *after* the argument list instead of *inside it*:

```
foo(1, { puts 'Hello' }) # wrong
foo(1) { puts 'Hello' }  # right
```

So, your code should look like:

```
[:rindex, :index].map {|sym| [0, 1, 2].send(sym) {|x| x %2 == 0 }}
```

Note: you should always prefer `public_send` over `send`. `send` does two things at once: allow the name of the message to be dynamic, and break encapsulation. If you use `send`, people who read your code are never quite sure which of the two features you are actually using. In this case, you are not breaking encapsulation at all, you are only using the dynamic message name. That's exactly what `public_send` does.

```
%i[rindex index].map {|meth| [0, 1, 2].public_send(meth, &:even?)}
```

This would be a more idiomatic way to write your code.

Answer (score 4):

To pass the closure, one should instruct the ruby parser, that it’s a block, using an ampersand character:

```
[ :rindex, :index ].map do |sym|
  [0,1,2].send(sym, &->(x){ x % 2 == 0  })
end
#⇒ [2, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

No rocket science option:

```
%i(rindex index).map { |meth| [0,1,2].public_send(meth) { |x| x % 2 == 0  } }
#=> [2, 0]
```

A bit shorter (using [Integer#`even?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Integer.html#method-i-even-3F)):

```
%i(rindex index).map { |meth| [0,1,2].public_send(meth, &:even?) }
#=> [2, 0]
```